# UITableView's tableViewHeader and tableViewCells overlapping until reloadData is called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a table view that has a `tableViewHeader` and a single section filled with cells.

Before I create my `UITableView`, I create a view called `topSection` which has the view's width and a variable height based on text that comes back from my API.

When I load the view controller, as the API call is in flight, very briefly I can see the `topSection` (which is the `UITableView.tableViewHeader`) sitting behind the `UITableViewCells`. Then when `reloadData` is called in my `didSet` to render the table view, everything lays out correctly.

I'm not constraining the `topSection` in any way before it's added to the `UITableView`

I also tried constraining the `top` of the `topSection` to the `tableView` `top` but that didn't work either.

```
let listingsTableView = UITableView()
    listingsTableView.backgroundColor = .white
    listingsTableView.dataSource = self
    listingsTableView.delegate = self
    listingsTableView.rowHeight = 78
    listingsTableView.bounces = false
    listingsTableView.allowsSelection = false
    listingsTableView.tableHeaderView = topSection
    listingsTableView.register(ListingsHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "HeaderView")
    listingsTableView.register(ListingsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ListingsCell")
    view.addSubview(listingsTableView)

    constrain(listingsTableView, topSection) { tableview, topSection in
        tableview.top == tableview.superview!.top
        tableview.left == tableview.superview!.left
        tableview.right == tableview.superview!.right
        tableview.bottom == tableview.superview!.bottom
    }
    self.listingsTableView = listingsTableView
```

Any help here would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, the default behavior of table view header is to be on top of the view. Cells scroll under it. If you don't want that behaviour don't use the above view as header view. Make it separate

Comment: I believe you're thinking of the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. That's the grey bar with "A," "B," etc. in the Contacts app, for example. The `UITableView.tableViewHeader` is a view that sits on top of all of the sections in the UIScrollView that is inherently part of the table view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're running into a common problem - the table doesn't "auto-size" the header view without a little prompting.

Try adding this to your code (you might need to change view references...):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    sizeHeaderToFit()
}

func sizeHeaderToFit() {
    let headerView = theTableView.tableHeaderView!

    headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height

    var frame = headerView.frame
    frame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = frame

    theTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Comment: Thanks DonMag! One small thing that happens as a result is that my UILabel which has a `numberOfLines` property equal to 0, a left margin and a width no long wraps, it just bleeds off the left side of the view. Seems to be a side effect of this

Comment: cl.ly/181p1D3a0X3J (add https:// to the front, won't let me post a link for some reason). It has a left constraint of the Title ("Nike"), a top Constraint of the Title's bottom + 4 and a width of the superview.width * 80% in addition to `numberOfLines = 0`

Comment: Is that part of the header view? Or a cell / row? Have you tried Debug Hierarchy to see if any constraints are missing or not getting calculated correctly?

Comment: it's part of the `tableViewHeader`. It's just another object laid out in the view. I'll take a look at the Debug Hierarchy

Comment: Got it fixed. Thanks for your help DonMag